# raw text cannot be used outside of a text tag. not rendering string ''

Tags: react-native

I keep getting this error on a Search form. I've set my initial state as an empty string.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    searchText: ''
  };
}
```

and then set it in the `TextInput` value

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ searchText: text })}
  value={this.state.searchText}
  placeholder={'Search'}
  placeholderTextColor={globalStyles.MUTED_COLOR}
/>
```

Should I be wrapping a `<Text>` into value?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is *whitespace*. Using "tabs" however does not count as *whitespace*. Try removing the space between the *tag* and the *comment*.